# How to Save Rendered HTML from Markdown in PyCharm

Tags: html, pycharm, markdown

When I export a markdown file to HTML in PyCharm, the result shows raw markdown rather than rendered. The preview pane shows the correct rendering. Is there a way to export to HTML so that headings, bullets, etc. render correctly?

Example of what the html output looks like in a browser:
[html output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETJlF.png)

Example of preview pane:
[html preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKnJ3.png)